# how to speed up FragmentTransaction animated

Tags: android, performance

I have single app activity and several screens which extend Fragment class. 
I change Fragments with animation using FragmentTransaction.replace(...). But I notice delay/lag: animation starts, then fragment inflate his view, and during this process animation is jerky.

I created class ScreenManager, where I create all fragment at startup, and inflate it at startup, then in onCreateView I just return inflated before view, but it works jerky also.

How I can start transaction after fragment became inflated?
How can I get smooth animation of fragment transaction?

thanks.